# Background color row in ObjectListView filtered by cell value - VB.NET WinForms

Tags: objectlistview

Good afternoon,

It's being complicated to solve the problem that i am facing.

I have a ObjectListView filled and need to distinguish the rows that have a specific value in a cell.

So, if the cell as a value of 1 -> yellow row, value of 2 -> orange row, and so on..

I used the default ObjectListView control provided, no code used.

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on their site includes a very similar example through configuring a handler for the FormatRow event.

[OLV Recipes](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html)

In my testing, however, I found that the event wasn't firing when I only used the SetObjects() method.  I was able to get the event to work correctly after also calling RefreshObjects().

Reviewing their code: SetObjects() never calls PostProcessOneRow().  I'm not sure if this is intentionally left out or a bug.