# How to change the color of one cell in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, listview, colors, cell, objectlistview

THIS IS NOT A PLAIN LISTVIEW!
I want to create a Windows Forms Application in C#. But i have some problems with the ObjectListView.
I want to change the color of one specific cell in the objectlistview but I can only change the color of one row. 
this is my objectlistview: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh8OY.png)

there you can see the column "Queue" and there is a value "Allgemein" and I want to color all these values with "Allgemein" in these column in red but not the whole row.

I changed with this code the color of the row:

```
objectListView1.Items[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set the BackColor of Winforms ListView cells individually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958171/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-backcolor-of-winforms-listview-cells-individually)

Comment: dude that is a plain listview not a objectlistview

Comment: Sorry you are right !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is well explained in this [ObjectListView cookbook](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row-or-just-a-cell).

Comment: OK thank you that was very helpful. but now I need to click on the column first to see the colors. Do you know why? Or can I bind that function to the form load event or to a button click?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862029/background-color-row-in-objectlistview-filtered-by-cell-value-vb-net-winforms) you need to call some method to apply the post processing (`RefreshObjects()`).

Comment: Maybe of interest: "To improve performance, FormatCell events are only fired when a handler of the FormatRow event sets UseCellFormatEvents to true. If you want to have a FormatCell event fired for every cell, you can set UseCellFormatEvents on the ObjectListView itself." - So it should work without problems when you set `UseCellFormatEvents` of the ObjectListView.

Answer (score 2):

Just In case someone needs this, if you want to change the color of the whole column (not header), use decoration.

There is a class `TintColumnDecoration`, used by default in OLV to tint sorted column, but you can customize it:

```
Dim MyTint= New TintedColumnDecoration(YourColumn)
MyTint.Tint = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.LightGreen)
OLV.AddDecoration(MyTint)
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/

[CellEditStarting event](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/cellEditing.html#celleditstarting-event)

The CellEditStarting event is triggered after the user has requested to edit a cell but before the cell editor is placed on the screen.

This event passes a **CellEditEventArgs** object to the event handlers. In the handler for this event, if you set e.Cancel to True , the cell editing operation will not begin. If you don’t cancel the edit operation, you will almost certainly want to play with the Control property of CellEditEventArgs.

You can use this to customise the default editor, or to replace it entirely.
For example, if your ObjectListView is showing a Color in a cell, there is no default editor to handle a Color. You could make your own ColorCellEditor, set it up correctly, and then set the Control property to be your color cell editor. The ObjectListView would then use that control rather than the default one. If you do this, you must fully configure your control, since the ObjectListView will not do any further configuration of the editor. So, to listen for the event, you would do something like this:

```
this.myObjectListView.CellEditStarting += new CellEditEventHandler(this.HandleCellEditStarting);
```

And your handler method might look something like this:

```
private void HandleCellEditStarting(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Value is Color) {
        ColorCellEditor cce = new ColorCellEditor();
        cce.Bounds = e.CellBounds;
        cce.Value = e.Value;
        e.Control = cce;
    }
}
```

With this code in place, your spiffy ColorCellEditor will be shown whenever the user tries to edit a color in your ObjectListView.

Comment: But is this not only when the user tries to edit a cell? because i want to color the cells when the program opens and the objects are loaded to the objectlstview?!

Comment: @Cortana why dont you explicitly call this handler when you are going to change the color